# Вывод данных через цикл for в JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Есть данные людей в ObservableList (личный номер, имя, сумма часов). Как отображать это списком через цикл for, причем в конце каждой строки добавлять поля для ввода? Из поля для ввода берутся часы и прибавляться к общей сумме. Вот такой формат:

Number - Name - Total - input

Как это реализовать с помощью цикла for ?

Comment: Не проще TableView использовать?

Comment: Проще, но мне нужно именно через for реализовать.

Comment: Ок, и в чем проблема? Создаете GridPane, в него построчно в цикле for добавляете контрол или контролы с данными, и справа поле ввода.